# Check sd-card availablity android

Tags: android, android-external-storage

In my application I want to check whether the SD-Card is present (asin mounted) or not. When I try to run the application I am getting "sd-card is mounted" even though its not there.

Code

```
public boolean isSDCardPresent() {

        return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    }
```

The above code always returns true even if the sd-card is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your method to this

```
public boolean isSDCardPresent() {

    return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

}
```

Comment: still am getting it as mounted

Comment: Are you testing it in an emulator?

Comment: Is it a Samsung device?

Comment: Nah its a videocon tab

Comment: It's probably a bug on your device. Try it on another device.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
public boolean isSDCardPresent() { 
    return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY);
}
```

Comment: In my device Nexus 9 tab. there is no SD card Slot and it returning false.

Comment: But if i put the sd-card it again returning false

Answer (score 0):

The external (removable) Sd path varies from device to device, I also couldn't figure out a single way to check its availability, so I wrote a method, which iterates through all the different ext paths that the different manufacturers use, and then it finds the exact match. Returns true if the folder is found & the card is inserted in the phone.

Note: I used [StreamSupport](http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) library inside the method, so you'll need to download the jar file and add it to libs folder of your project and that's it, it'll work!

```
   public static boolean isExternalCardAvailable(Context context) {
    List<String> listOfFoldersToSearch = Arrays.asList("/storage/", "/mnt/", "/removable/", "/data/");
    final List<String> listOf2DepthFolders = Arrays.asList("sdcard0", "media_rw", "removable");
    final List<String> listOfExtFolders = Arrays.asList("sdcard1", "extsdcard", "external_sd", "microsd", "emmc", "ext_sd", "sdext",
            "sdext1", "sdext2", "sdext3", "sdext4");
    final String[] thePath = {""};
    Optional<File> optional = StreamSupport.stream(listOfFoldersToSearch)
            .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(final String s) {
                    File folder = new File(s);
                    return folder.exists() && folder.isDirectory();
                }
            }) //I got the ones that exist and are directories
            .flatMap(new Function<String, Stream<File>>() {
                @Override
                public Stream<File> apply(final String s) {
                    try {
                        List<File> files = Arrays.asList(new File(s).listFiles());
                        return StreamSupport.stream(files);
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        return StreamSupport.stream(new ArrayList<File>());
                    }
                }
            }) //I got all sub-dirs of the main folders
            .flatMap(new Function<File, Stream<File>>() {
                @Override
                public Stream<File> apply(final File file1) {
                    if (listOf2DepthFolders.contains(file1.getName()
                            .toLowerCase())) {
                        try {
                            List<File> files = Arrays.asList(file1.listFiles());
                            return StreamSupport.stream(files);
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            return StreamSupport.stream(Collections.singletonList(file1));
                        }
                    } else
                        return StreamSupport.stream(Collections.singletonList(file1));
                }
            }) //Here I got all the 2 depth and 3 depth folders
            .filter(new Predicate<File>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(final File o) {
                    return listOfExtFolders.contains(o.getName()
                            .toLowerCase());
                }
            })
            .findFirst();

    optional.ifPresent(new Consumer<File>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(final File file) {
            thePath[0] = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    });

    Log.e("Path", thePath[0]);

    try {
        ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("PathException", thePath[0]);
    }
    return !thePath[0].equals("") && new File(thePath[0]).listFiles()!=null;
}
```

P.S. I tested and verified it on a few HTC and Samsung devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had a pretty similar problem yesterday:

I wanted to check, if there's a physical Sd-Card in my device.

the Problem was that

```
public boolean isSDCardPresent() {

return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);}
```

always returned true (even if the sd-Card was physically removed) , because of the emulated sd-card.

so this is my solution:

```
static boolean externalStoragecheck() {
    return !Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated();
}
```

Haven't found anything like this, so I wanted to share this with you.